# Limit $\lim _{t\to 0 }\frac{ \int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-xt}}{\pi^2+(\log x)^2}dx }{ \int_0^{1/t}\frac{dx}{(\log x)^2}}$

Tags: integration, limits

$$
\mbox{Prove}\qquad
\lim _{t \to 0}{\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}{\mathrm{e}^{-xt} \over
\pi^{2} + \log^{2}\left(x\right)}\,\mathrm{d}x
\over
\displaystyle
\int_{0}^{1/t}{\mathrm{d}x \over \ln^{2}\left(x\right)}}
\qquad\mbox{tends to a finite limit.}
$$

- ( It might be the case that the limit is in fact $1$, but I am not sure. )
- I was not able to find any theorem regarding a situation in which both the range and function depends on $t$.
- The Monotone Convergence theorems I have seen are the closest related, but they are either only for "function independent of $t$ and range dependent on $t$" or "function dependent on $t$ and range independent of $t$".

Any help appreciated !.

Comment: You are asking for $\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-xt}}{\pi^2+(\log x)^2}dx}{\int_0^{1/t}\frac{dx}{(\log x)^2}}$ right? Can you not just use L'Hopital's rule here since it is an $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ indeterminate form?

Comment: Never mind, I see the problem with using L'Hopital. I do not think that would work because $\frac{1}{\ln(x)^2}$ is discontinuous at $x = 1$.

Comment: THe integral if the denominator, $\int^{1/t}_0\frac{dx}{(\log^2x)}=\infty$ for $t<1$. The integral in the numerator is finite and positive for all $t>0$. Thus, if the limits of integration in the denominator are meant to be what you intended, the fraction is zero for all $0<t<1$.

Comment: @DesmondMiles Hi Desmond! It's been a while. I hope you're staying safe and healthy during the pandemic. I've reached out to contact you a few times, but am unsure whether you've received the notes? If you would, please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. And feel free to up vote an answer as you see fit. ;-)

Answer (score 6):

First, noting that $\frac1{\log^2(x)}\sim \frac1{(x-1)^2}$ as $x\to 1$, the integral $\int_0^{1/t}\frac{1}{\log^2(x)}\,dx$ diverges for all $t<1$ due to the sharp singularity at $x=1$.

So, let's look instead at the integral
$$f(t)=\int_C^{1/t}\frac{1}{\log^2(x)}\,dx\tag1$$
for $C>1$, $t<1$.  Using integration by parts on the integral in $(1)$, we see that
$$\begin{align}
f(t)&=\int_C^{1/t}\frac1{\log^2(x)}\,dx\\\\
&\overbrace{=}^{\text{IBP}}\frac{1}{t\log^2(t)}-\frac{C}{\log^2(C)}-\int_{C}^{1/t}\frac1{\log^3(x)}\,dx\\\\
&=\frac{1}{t\log^2(t)}+O\left(\frac1{t\log^3(t)}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{1+o(1)}{t\log^2(t)}\tag2
\end{align}$$

---

---

Now, let's investigate the integral $g(t)=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-xt}}{\pi^2+\log^2(x)}\,dx$.  Enforcing the substitution $xt\mapsto x$ reveals
$$\begin{align}
g(t)&=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-xt}}{\pi^2+\log^2(x)}\,dx\\\\
&=\frac1{t \log^2(t)}\int_0^\infty \frac{\log^2(t)}{\pi^2+\log^2(x/t)}e^{-x}\,dx\\\\
&=\frac1{t \log^2(t)}\int_0^{\sqrt{t}} \frac{\log^2(t)}{\pi^2+\log^2(x/t)}e^{-x}\,dx\\\\
&+\frac1{t \log^2(t)}\int_{\sqrt{t}}^\infty \frac{\log^2(t)}{\pi^2+\log^2(x/t)}e^{-x}\,dx\tag3
\end{align}$$
For the first integral on the right-hand side of $(3)$, we make use of the estimate $\frac{1}{\pi^2+\log^2(x/t)}\le \frac{1}{\pi^2}$. Then, we have for the first integral
$$\begin{align}
0&\le \frac1{t \log^2(t)}\int_0^{\sqrt{t}} \frac{\log^2(t)}{\pi^2+\log^2(x/t)}e^{-x}\,dx\\\\
&\le \frac1{t\log^2(t)} \frac{\left(1-e^{-\sqrt{t}}\right)\log^2(t)}{\pi^2 }\\\\
&=\frac{o(1)}{t\log^2(t)}
\end{align}$$
For the second integral we make use of the estimate $\left|\xi_{x\ge \sqrt t}(x)\frac{\log^2(t)}{\pi^2+\log^2(x/t)}e^{-x}\right|\le \frac{\log^2(t)}{\pi^2+\frac14\log^2(t)}e^{-x}\le 4e^{-x}$. Then, we apply the Dominated Convergence Theorem to reveal
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{t\to 0}\int_{\sqrt{t}}^\infty \frac{\log^2(t)}{\pi^2+\log^2(x/t)}e^{-x}\,dx&=\lim_{t\to 0}\int_{0}^\infty \xi_{x\ge \sqrt t}(x)\frac{\log^2(t)}{\pi^2+\log^2(x/t)}e^{-x}\,dx\\\\
&\int_{0}^\infty \lim_{t\to 0}\left(\xi_{x\ge \sqrt{t}}(x)\frac{\log^2(t)}{\pi^2+\log^2(x/t)}\right)e^{-x}\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\,dx\\\\
&=1
\end{align}$$

from which we conclude

$$\frac1{t\log^2(t)}\int_{\sqrt{t}}^\infty \frac{\log^2(t)}{\pi^2+\log^2(x/t)}e^{-x}\,dx=\frac{1+o(1)}{t\log^2(t)}$$

Now just put everything together and finish it off.

Comment: it seems that in the original problem the numerator $\int^{1/t}_0\frac{dx}{\log^2x}=\infty$ for all $0<t<1$ since, as you pointed out, $\log^{-2}x\sim\ (1-x)^{-2}$ and so $\int^1_0\frac{dx}{\log^2x}=\infty$. My point being is that the ratio in the original problem is always $0$ for $0<t<1$. Were  the lower limit in the integral of the denominator to be changed to $C>1$, then your careful asymptotic will be useful.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Indeed.  Inasmuch as the limit of the original quotient is $0$ for all $t\in (0,1]$, the problem is trivial.  However, if the lower limit of the denominator is $C>1$, then the problem becomes interesting.

Comment: @DesmondMiles Hi Desmond! It's been a while. I hope you're staying safe and healthy during the pandemic. I've reached out to contact you a few times, but am unsure whether you've received the notes? If you would, please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. And feel free to up vote an answer as you see fit. ;-)